# Can I name part of a table name after a variable?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to create a table that takes part of declared variable and concatenate it with table 
names etc.

like below?

apologies if I am phrasing the question wrong.

```
Declare @year int


set @year = 2019


CREATE TABLE tab_@Year 
(  
Field1 nvarchar(50),  
Field2 datetime,   
Field3 datetime,  
Field4 nvarchar(50),   
Field5 nvarchar(15)  
)    

insert into tab_@Year   

"select statement goes here"

select *    from tab_@year
```

EDIT*
I left out my end result, so i would be looking for a table to be created in the above scenario called

tab_2019

Comment: Simple answer, no. Long answer, yes, with dynamic SQL, however, the variable will only persist in the dynamic statement and thus would defeat the object. What is your real goal here?

Comment: hi @Larnu, i'm asked to generate data once every year, it goes to a table and i reference this table for other queries as they come in. it would be great to just run this once and change the year as needed when i go to it. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: So what does that have to do with table variables at all, especially ones with dynamic names. If you do need a table variable, then there seems no need for the name to change.

Comment: Why don't you do things "the other way round". Use a static name that never changes. When you start this process for the "current year" (presumably 2019 but you decide), rename that table to <name>_2018 (for example) and then recreate the table completely. You will need dynamic sql for that bit but everything else remains unchanged in your script/process.

Comment: And that assumes you need to keep this old information around for some reason. If not, just truncate the table.

Comment: Why not create one table, with a column for Year, and just query on the required year?

Comment: Apologies to all for the lateness in replying, my real goal here, is to simply run a query for a finance department where i simply enter in the year. I then save this data and email it to them so they can do what ever they need to it. So i enter 2019, it pulls data from a linked readonly server and compares data against some data in our database. It may sound horrible and it is, but it gets the job done. Thanks for all help and advice from everyone!

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @year varchar(225)
Declare @q nvarchar(1000)
Declare @q2 nvarchar(1000)
set @year = 2020
set @q='CREATE TABLE tab_'+@Year+'
(  
Field1 nvarchar(50),  
Field2 datetime,   
Field3 datetime,  
Field4 nvarchar(50),   
Field5 nvarchar(15)  
)'
exec (@q)

set @q2='insert into tab_'+@Year+' values (1,1,1,1,1)'
exec (@q2)
```